# How to add some self process when using Python eve?

Tags: python, flask, eve

How to add some self process when using Python eve ?

For example, this is my activity schema.

```
schema = {
        'id': {
            'type': 'integer',
            'readonly': True,
            'unique': True,
        },

        'name': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 3,
            'maxlength': 20,
            'required': True,
        },

        'date': {
            'type': 'datetime',
        },

        'location': {
            'type': 'string',
        },

        'icon': {
            'type': 'media',
        },

        'type': {
            'type': 'integer',
            'allowed': [i for i in range(5)],
        },

        'info': {
            'type': 'list',
        },

        'share': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'readonly': True,
            'schema': {
                'url': {
                    'type': 'string',
                },
                'qr': {
                    'type': 'media',
                }
            }
        },
        'publisher': {
            'type': 'list',
        },
        'participators': {
            'type': 'list',
        },
     }
```

And I want to generate a share url and qr-code when the activity is creatd using POST, and give it a simple ID like 001, I have achieve the code to generate something like qr-code generator, but I don't how to add all these function after info to be POSTed and before being saved to MongoDB.

I have seen something like Event Hook, but I still didn't know how to achieve that like fixing the POST data or some other func.

Can u just show me some datail example, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on_insert` event is fired *after* the `POST` request has been validated and parsed and *before* the documents are sent to the database. You could hook a callback function to `on_insert` and manipulate the payload at wish, like so:

```
from eve import Eve

def manipulate_inbound_documents(resource, docs):
    if resource == 'activity':
        for doc in docs:
            doc['id_field'] = '001'
            doc['qr'] = 'mycqcode'

app = Eve()
app.on_insert += manipulate_inbound_documents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can also use `on_insert_<resourcename>`, like so:

```
# note that the signature has changed
def manipulate_inbound_documents(docs):
    # no need to branch on the resource name
    for doc in docs:
        doc['id_field'] = '001'
        doc['qr'] = 'mycqcode'

app = Eve()
# only fire the event on 'activity' endpoint
app.on_insert_activity += manipulate_inbound_documents
```

Second approach makes every callback function super-specialized and improves code isolation. Also remember that you can hook multiple callbacks to the same event (hence the unary operator.)

For reference, see [the docs](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks)

Comment: But this way just change the response to user, but what actually saved in db is still what our request got, isn't it? I actually need some methods to have a fix while data being saved like I got "John" in name field and I want to save a link like "t.co/john". So I have to use request.args.get() to get John and then use pymongo to insert the data into Mongo, am I right. I've actually confused for a long time.

Comment: Nope since you are changing the payload *before* it is sent to the database, you are changing the database document too.

Comment: Perfectly and I suggest you to add this example and explaination to your doc and it will surely help so many other guys.